# CKeditor removes iframes in editor after update to 6.x-1.14

Tags: 6, wysiwyg

Similar to [this](https://drupal.org/node/1950498) issue on the CKeditor project, CKeditor removes embedded iframes after I've updated the module. Though there is a solution in the first comment for Drupal 7, I can't find a solution for this for Drupal 6.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: this fixes this issue in d7, when the media icon not is in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **ckeditor.config.js**, add `config.allowedContent = true;` to disable the filtering of HTML elements in the editor.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
}
```